# Call to undefined function to_date laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello guys please help me , i 'm having "Call to undefined function to_date()" when i try to run this query.

```
return $employees = \DB::table('employees')
                       ->whereBetween(
                           'HIRE_DATE',
                           array(
                               \to_date('13/01/01','mm/dd/yyyy'),
                               \to_date('07/06/02','mm/dd/yyyy')
                           )
                       )
                       ->get();
```

I'm using jfelder Oracle DB driver , many thanks in advance.

Comment: `date("mm/dd/yyyy", strtotime("13/01/01"));` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) for dates in Laravel.

You need something like this:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '13/01/01')->format('Y-m-d'); // Inside the format you want, see php.net datetime class
```

Note: you need to install Carbon via Composer in Laravel 5. Just click [this](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) link for more information.

Comment: It was solved using: \DB::select("select * from employees where HIRE_DATE between to_date('28/06/04') and to_date('28/06/06')");

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have found a solution. But here is another way to fix your issue.

The error is because you have mixed syntax of SQL and PHP.

As you are trying to use `to_date` function of Oracle you need to wrap those calls inside `DB::raw()`.

```
return $employees = \DB::table('employees')
    ->whereBetween(
        'HIRE_DATE',
        array(
            \DB::raw("to_date('13/01/01','mm/dd/yyyy')"),
            \DB::raw("to_date('07/06/02','mm/dd/yyyy')")
        )
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: Using the option DB::raw() as you said i 'm having "oci_bind_by_name(): Invalid variable used for bind " error i just copy past it.

Comment: Might be because driver you are using has no support for  `DB::raw`. My bad. I didn't check the driver before I answer :(